# Function from imported swig wrapped module not found

Tags: python, swig

I want to create several Python modules from SWIG-wrapped C++ classes.
The problem is that modules cannot import each other.

here is A_module.i file

```
%module A_module
%inline
%{
    void foo(){}
%}
```

it compiles without problem, thus in .py script I can do something like this:

```
import A_module
A_module.foo()
```

Now I want to create B_module that import A_module and calls foo.
Here is B_module.i file

```
%module B_module
%import A_module.i
```

When I do something like this in .py

```
import B_module
B_module.foo()
```

It gives an error syaing module has no attribute foo.

The solution I've found is to use %include instead of import, but it creates same foo function in both modules, which I would like to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That .i `%import` is a Python `import`, so the `foo` you're looking for lives as `B_module.A_module.foo`. You can use Python code explicitly to import and copy parts of A_module into B_module. For example, have as `B_module.i`:

```
%module B_module

%pythoncode %{
import A_module
foo = A_module.foo
del A_module
%}
```